# R Shiny input slider range values

Tags: r, input, slider, shiny

I have a slider input type of 'range' in my Shiny app and I would like to get the minimum and maximum values selected by the user in my server.R

in my ui.R I have

```
sliderInput("range", "Age:",
min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0,100))
```

and I would like to get the selected values not min and max that I have defined

Comment: @user2100721 you compare a selectInput with a inputSlider ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can access the slider ranges using `input$range[1]` for min and `input$range[2]` for max

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(sliderInput("range", "Age:",min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0,100)),textOutput("SliderText"))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  my_range <- reactive({
    cbind(input$range[1],input$range[2])
})
output$SliderText <- renderText({my_range()})
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]